# How to get the sourcecode of an element created in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, console, output, element

I created this element with Javascript.

```
var divElem = document.createElement("div");
divElem.setAttribute("id", "testedMeter");
divElem.setAttribute("class", "meter");
document.getElementById('testDiv').appendChild(divElem);
console.log(divElem);
```

When I output it into the console with console.log, I am getting the source code of this element.

```
<div id="testedMeter" class="meter"></div>
```

When i output divElem into a div it just says [object HTMLDivElement].
My Question is, how can I output the sourcecode of divElem into a div, textarea or something, so that i can copy the sourcecode? I need this, because i create thousend of those elements with different ids.

Comment: JSON.stringify(divElem)

Comment: It just returns {}

Comment: @Observer `JSON.stringify()` isn't going to help on a non-JavaScript object.

Comment: try divElem.outerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `textarea.value = divElem.outerHTML`

[MDN Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the element's HTML as a string with **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)**:

```js
var divElem = document.createElement("div");
divElem.setAttribute("id", "testedMeter");
divElem.setAttribute("class", "meter");

// First, append the element as you did before:
document.getElementById('testDiv').appendChild(divElem);

// Now, you can pull out that child element's HTML with .innerHTML and put that 
// string anywhere you like:
document.getElementById('testDiv').textContent = document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="testDiv" class="meter"></div>
```